# Formula to subtract left side from right side of a cell value, and print result (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel, vba

I tried looking around for an answer to this but kinda got lost...

Here's my situation:

---

-I have 2 numbers in some cells of column D whose difference I want displayed on the same row in column E.

-Not all rows will use this formula, but those that do are grouped together

---

-Column D's format is set to text because I want all leading/ending zeroes to show. Each value is entered in manually - 
2 nums delimited by a UTF-8 tilde (no spaces), i.e. 000.000～000.001

-Column E's format is set to Standard, otherwise formulae won't work. Cell at Column E (Row x) is where I want the difference between the right and the left numbers of the value of the cell in Column D (Row x) to be spat out.
(Since I've manually entered the numbers, I make sure the right number will always be bigger than the left.)

I realize I could do this in VBA but since the workbook is shared, adding a macro isn't possible without unsharing it. And some object to that. Therefore I'd prefer a formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, Here is an example of how to grab parts of a cells value:

```
A1 = 100~200
```

---

```
B1 = =LEFT(A1,FIND("~",A1)-1) + RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",A1))
```

B1 Result = 300

Comment: The Plus doesn't have a bearing on the split, I am using the Tilde (~) position to calculate where to take the left and right parts, I am adding the two together just to show that Excel is smart enough to understand the two parts are numbers :)

Comment: I see I had to make the cell format normal, and not text in order to make the formula run.  I changed the formula to this and it worked for me    =RIGHT($D27,LEN($D27)-FIND("～",$D27) - LEFT($D27,FIND("～",$D27)-1) )  but when I copy paste it to a different cell in a different row it doesn`t look like the row is updating...

Comment: What does it do when you copy it to another row? What does it update the row reference to?

Comment: It displays #VALUE.  Below I have illustrated what I'm doing more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I very slightly edited Dan D's original formula to get it to suit my needs :

=RIGHT(D27,LEN(D27)-FIND("～",D27) - LEFT(D27,FIND("～",D27)-1) )

With the above formula only when the Left number is 000.000 is the correct difference displayed.  Otherwise it's #VALUE.

So, with this formula (thx to Dan D.) the correct difference is displayed:

=VALUE(RIGHT(D27,LEN(D27)-FIND("～",D27)) - VALUE(LEFT(D27,FIND("～",D27)-1)))

(Able to successfully copy-paste formula only by pasting one by one, though.)

Note: D27 in the formula above is the cell containing the values I need the difference of.  I just slap this formula into whichever normal/standard format cell I want the result to be displayed in.

Comment: Wrap it in a value formula =VALUE(RIGHT(D27,LEN(D27)-FIND("～",D27)) - VALUE(LEFT(D27,FIND("～",D27)-1)))